# Countable representation of ${X>0}$ as unions of $1/k^2$

Tags: probability, analysis, elementary-set-theory

How would I go about proving that the set $\{X>0\}$ can be written in the form firstly, $\bigcup_{\epsilon >0} \{X > \epsilon\}$ and then $\bigcup_{k \geq 1} \{X >1/k^2\}$. It seems so obvious that I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Many thanks.

Comment: Show each element of one is an element of the other and similarly in the other direction

Answer (score 0):

$$
\{X>0\}
\iff\{X > \epsilon \}\,\exists\,\epsilon > 0$$

and then this can be writed as $$
\bigcup_{\epsilon>0}\{X>\epsilon\}
$$
The union of $\epsilon$ can be understood as exists $\epsilon$ corresponding to the symbol $\exists$ and the Intersection corresponding to the symbol $\forall$

By the way, $\{X \ge 0\} \iff \{X > 0 -\epsilon\} \text { for any } \epsilon >0$
so , which can be write as following
$$
\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\{X>-\epsilon\}
$$

Comment: Hope to help you